# How can I send email notification to the mail address I entered in the form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I want to send email notification the mail address I entered in the response.

I tried this script in google forms Apps Script but I am unable to read **"<EMAIL_ADDRESS>"** in the last code. Have added a google form link as well with this script. Thanks!!

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1io_qYZTnf97Yyotw4hdWTLfaQElALaLx0TBifHPge7c/edit

```
// Restrict the script's authorization
// to the form it is bound to.

//@OnlyCurrentDoc

// Create a form submit installable trigger
// using Apps Script.
function createFormSubmitTrigger() {

  // Get the form object.
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // See if the trigger has already been set up.
  // Since we know this project should only have a single trigger
  // we'll simply check if there are more than 0 triggers. If yes,
  // we'll assume this function was already run so we won't create
  // a trigger.
  var currentTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if(currentTriggers.length > 0)
    return;
  
  // Create a trigger that will run the onFormSubmit function
  // whenever the form is submitted.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
}

// A function that is called by the form submit
// trigger. The parameter e contains information
// submitted by the user.
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 
  // Get the response that was submitted.
  var formResponse = e.response;

  // Get the items (i.e., responses to various questions)
  // that were submitted.
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // Create a variable emailBody to store the body
  // of the email notification to be sent.
  var emailBody = "New form response:\n\n";
   

  // Put together the email body by appending all the
  // questions & responses to the variable emailBody.
  itemResponses.forEach(function(itemResponse) {
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    var response = itemResponse.getResponse();
    emailBody += title + "\n" + response + "\n\n";
  });

  // Send the email notification using the
  // sendEmail() function.
  sendEmail(emailBody);
}

// A function that sends the email
// notification.
function sendEmail(emailBody) {
  MailApp.sendEmail("<EMAIL_ADDRESS>", "New form response", emailBody);
}`
```

Tried reading the google form responses and fetching the mail address.

Comment: Do you collect respondents' email address in your form? if you do, it should not be hard to get this to work

Comment: In the settings section of your form, you can collect email address, on top of that, you can turn ON the option "Send responders a copy of their response"